How to check if a file exists in SQLite3
For my project I need to make a database and one of the requirements is that it must check if the file exists, I have tried but my code doesn't work when I try. I have watched many tutorials and none of them work, please help me (I would prefer the corrected code instead of just text because whenever I try that it doesn't work). The main issue is that the selection doesn't work after the database is created, you can't check if the variables work. I would also happily accept any other tips or suggestions.
Here is my code:
import sqlite3
from replit import clear
import time as t

bd = sqlite3.connect('Builds.db')

cursor = bd.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE Builds (
        Build TEXT,
        Weapon TEXT,
        Aspect TEXT,
        Keepsakes TEXT,
        Arcana TEXT,
        Boons TEXT,
        Hammers TEXT
    )
''')


data = [
    ('Pan Snipe', ' Sister Blades', ' Aspect of Pan',' Keepsakes: Transcendant Embryo, Aromatic Phial, Knuckle Bones or Luckier Tooth', ' Arcana Cards: None', ' Boons: Poseidon- Wave Flourish (Heroic), Hera- Engangment Ring (Rare), Artemis- Death Warrant', ' Hammers: Spiral Knives and Dancing Knives')
]


cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO Builds (Build, Weapon, Aspect, Keepsakes, Arcana, Boons, Hammers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', data)

while True:
    clear()
    selection = input("""
    1) View list of builds
    2) Add to build list
    3) Search for name of build
    4) Delete build from build lsit
    5) Quit

    Enter your selection: """)

    if selection == "1":
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Builds')
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print(row)
            t.sleep(15)
    elif selection == "2":
        build_name = input("Build name: ")
        weapon = input("Enter Weapon: ")
        aspect = input("Enter Aspect: ")
        keepsake = input("Enter Keepsakes: ")
        arcana = input("Enter Arcana: ")
        boons = input("Enter Boons: ")
        hammers = input("Enter Hammers: ")
        print("")
        new_data = (None, build_name, weapon, aspect, keepsake, arcana, boons, hammers)
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', new_data)
        bd.commit()
    elif selection == "3":
        search_term = input("Enter build to search: ")
        print("")
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Builds WHERE Build = ?', (search_term,))
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print(row)
            t.sleep(15)
    elif selection == "4":
        id_to_delete = input("Enter build to delete: ")
        print("")
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Builds WHERE Buils = ?', (id_to_delete,))
        bd.commit()
    elif selection == "5":
        break
    else:
        print("")
        print("Incorrect selection, please try again.")
        print("")


bd.close()

I tried to use many other tutorials online but none of them worked

Why are you using clear()?

I am using clear() so the console doesn't get flooded

You can use pathlib.Path to check if files exist.
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = Path("path/to/some/file.sqlite")
    if path.is_file():
        # do your thing
        print("Database exists and is a file.")


But this isn't your problem.

You're trying to create the Builds table, regardless of whether it already exists.
You're creating a Builds table, but try to INSERT INTO Names, and you're inserting the wrong number of values. That won't work.

Here's an amended version:
import sqlite3
from replit import clear
import time as t


def main():
    bd = sqlite3.connect('Builds.db')

    cursor = bd.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Builds (
            Build TEXT,
            Weapon TEXT,
            Aspect TEXT,
            Keepsakes TEXT,
            Arcana TEXT,
            Boons TEXT,
            Hammers TEXT
        )
    ''')

    data = [
        ('Pan Snipe', ' Sister Blades', ' Aspect of Pan',
         ' Keepsakes: Transcendant Embryo, Aromatic Phial, Knuckle Bones or Luckier Tooth', ' Arcana Cards: None',
         ' Boons: Poseidon- Wave Flourish (Heroic), Hera- Engangment Ring (Rare), Artemis- Death Warrant',
         ' Hammers: Spiral Knives and Dancing Knives')
    ]

    cursor.executemany(
        'INSERT INTO Builds (Build, Weapon, Aspect, Keepsakes, Arcana, Boons, Hammers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        data)

    while True:
        clear()
        selection = input("""
        1) View list of builds
        2) Add to build list
        3) Search for name of build
        4) Delete build from build list
        5) Quit

        Enter your selection: """)

        if selection == "1":
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Builds')
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                print(row)
                t.sleep(1)
        elif selection == "2":
            build_name = input("Build name: ")
            weapon = input("Enter Weapon: ")
            aspect = input("Enter Aspect: ")
            keepsake = input("Enter Keepsakes: ")
            arcana = input("Enter Arcana: ")
            boons = input("Enter Boons: ")
            hammers = input("Enter Hammers: ")
            print()
            new_data = (build_name, weapon, aspect, keepsake, arcana, boons, hammers)
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Builds (Build, Weapon, Aspect, Keepsakes, Arcana, Boons, Hammers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', new_data)
            bd.commit()
        elif selection == "3":
            search_term = input("Enter build to search: ")
            print()
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Builds WHERE Build = ?', (search_term,))
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                print(row)
                t.sleep(1)
        elif selection == "4":
            id_to_delete = input("Enter build to delete: ")
            print()
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Builds WHERE Build = ?', (id_to_delete,))
            bd.commit()
        elif selection == "5":
            break
        else:
            print("\nIncorrect selection, please try again.\n")

    bd.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


This has one problem that it prints the build twice, can you please fix this? Thank You for making it work though

@HoloGrain This looks like a learning exercise, right? I'd suggest you do that yourself, or you won't improve. Also, this wasn't part of the question, so if you want something separate, you should ask another question
